# Java custom enum value to enum

Tags: java, enums

I have enum like this

```
public enum Sizes {
    Normal(232), Large(455);

    private final int _value;

    Sizes(int value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    public int Value() {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

Now I can call Sizes.Normal.Value() to get integer value, but how do I convert integer value back to enum?

What I do now is:

```
public Sizes ToSize(int value) {
    for (Sizes size : Sizes.values()) {
        if (size.Value() == value)
            return size;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But that's only way to do that?  That's how Java works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java enum reverse look-up best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316311/java-enum-reverse-look-up-best-practice)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes that's how it's done, generally by adding a static method to the enum. Think about it; you could have 10 fields on the enum. Do you expect Java to set up lookups for all of them?

The point here is that Java enums don't have a 'value'. They have identity and an ordinal, plus whatever you add for yourself. This is just different from C#, which follows C++ in having an arbitrary integer value instead.

Comment: I tried to put a static HashMap into his enum, but it appears that you aren't allowed to fill it from within the enum constructor. 1+

Comment: well I still prefer how C# handles enums. Its much faster. Enum suppose to be a integer Identifier, not the entire class :)

Comment: You might need to initialize it in a static block. static private HashMap<xxx,xxx> map = new HashMap<xxx,xxx>; and then do puts in the ctor?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I tried too, and it says Cannot refer to the static enum field Sizes.ValuesHolder within an initializer

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316311/java-enum-reverse-look-up-best-practice.

Comment: @bmargulies: wow thats exactly what I just did, using static constructor. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I last worked with Java, but if I recall correctly, there's no relation between your `_value` field and the enum's ordinal. AFAIK you could have two entries with the same `_value`, for instance. As @bmargulies pointed out, you could have many fields in the enum, and nothing constrain you to use distinct values for each (or all) of them.

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5372855/520779). Apparently, you can't directly set the ordinal of your entries.

Comment: thats why I asked, I was thinking there could be built-in support in java like C# but I have to write everything. Its like working in C++ lol