# Thymeleaf enum values in a dropdown list reverse order

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, enums, thymeleaf

I have a domain object that has an enum property and I want to display a dropdown list with all possible enum values but in reverse order

```
<select th:field="*{level}" >
                                        <option th:each="level : ${ T(com.nicinc.enums.AlarmLevelEnum).values()}" 
                                                th:value="${level}" 
                                                th:text="${level}"></option>
                                    </select>
```

Is there a change I could do it ?

Comment: You can use an util-library but I think you should locate such logic to your controller and not your thymeleaf template.

Comment: I would create a method in your Enum as reverseValues() and add that List to your controller. Easier to unerstand and read

Comment: just do this in the controller and put the values in the model from the controller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762438/how-to-reverse-enum